# Primary Key or Index for querying Hive in Apache Drill

Tags: indexing, hive, primary-key, apache-drill

What will be the primary key or index while querying Hive in Apache Drill and how to execute those queries?

Answer (score 0):

As of Drill 1.12, Drill does not leverage indices. Drill just assumes there are no indices and sucks in all the data and does the compute in a naive fashion. There is work to leverage knowledge of indices in external systems like Hive, but the work is ongoing and not yet part of a Drill release.

Comment: True. But to be fair, all Big Data query engines _(Hive, Impala, Drill, Spark... even Oracle Exadata in a way)_ have the same approach to minimize I/O: rely on (a) partitioning/bucketing and (b) "predicate push-down" supported by columnar formats such as Parquet and ORC -- cf. https://drill.apache.org/docs/partition-pruning-introduction/ and https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-filter-pushdown/

Comment: Drill does support partitioning files and does do predicate pushdown. However, it does not support indices (yet). For example if you have a database table with column **myCol** and an index defined on **myCol** Drill will not take advantage of the index to do something like a sort. Instead Drill will suck in all the data from the table and do a sort, even if there is an index defined on the column.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said, there was nothing about _" (c) indices"_ ... 0 : -)